# How to retrieve the values of XML Attributes without the names of the respective attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using `XDocument` with C#.

I have the following XML-data, from which I want to extract the ids (c5946, cdb9fb, etc.):

```
<rootElement>
    <IDs>
       <ID value="c5946"/>
       <ID value="cdb9fb"/>
       <ID value="c677f5"/>
       <ID value="ccc78b"/>
   </IDs>
</rootElement>
```

I tried different stuff, among others, this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var Ids = xDoc.Root.Element("IDs").Elements("ID").Attributes("value");
```

But this returns:

```
 value="c5946", value="cdb9fb", etc.
```

instead of

```
c5946, cdb9fb, etc.
```

How can I get the values of the attributes without the name of the respective attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Value` property of attribute

```
var allId = document.Descendants("ID").Select(id => id.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Or you can cast `XAttribute` to the `string`

```
var allId = document.Descendants("ID").Select(id => (string)id.Attribute("value"));
```

Casting will be simpler approach in case when attribute not exists in the element.

```
var allId = document.Descendants("ID").Select(id => (string)id.Attribute("value") ?? "");
```